# Jquery click function only triggers animation first time

Tags: onclick, animate.css

there are already many posts that are related to my problem. Yet I couldn't find a solution. I must say that I am quite a Javascript beginner.

I want to put an animated overlay on every single of 4 sliders with the background-color being animated gradually after having clicked. The sliders switch when clicked on a button with a class called "tparrows". I added an empty, absolute positioned div to each of the 4 sliders called "overlay-wrapper" that should be filled with background-color using keyframes.

HTML of single slider element (Slider Revolution)

```
<ul>
        <li data-transition="fade"><div class="overlay-wrapper"></div><img src="images/slider/picture.jpg" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"/>
          <h1 class="tp-caption large sfr" data-x="30" data-y="213" data-speed="600" data-start="800" data-easing="Sine.easeOut"><span>Some Text</span></h1>
          <h2 class="tp-caption medium sfr" data-x="30" data-y="310" data-speed="800" data-start="900" data-easing="Sine.easeOut"><span>Some Text</span></h2>
          <h3 class="tp-caption small sfr" data-x="30" data-y="450" data-speed="900" data-start="1000" data-easing="Sine.easeOut"><span><span class="budicon-plus"></span>Some Text</span></h3>

        </li>
...
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.overlay-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(55, 55, 59, 0.5);
    -webkit-animation: bg-color-anim 9s ease-in;
    animation: bg-color-anim 9s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg-color-anim {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(55, 55, 59, 0);
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(55, 55, 59, 0.5);
    }
}
@keyframes bg-color-anim {
    0% {
        background-color: rgba(55, 55, 59, 0);
    }
    100% {
        background-color: rgba(55, 55, 59, 0.5);
    }
}
```

This is my Jquery that should add the class (overlay) with animation to the div (overlay-wrapper) when button (tparrows) is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tparrows").on('click', function () {  //  here $(this) is refering to document
    $(".overlay-wrapper").addClass('overlay');
    });
});
```

It is working though but only the first click! The next time the background is added but without animation.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you very much!
Cheers,
Pierre

Comment: Please post your html as well.

Comment: try creating code snippet

Comment: just did, thanks Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code here. It will help to understand problem. I used `toggleClass` jquery method to add/remove class.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tparrows").on('click', function () {  //  here $(this) is refering to document
    $(".tparrows").toggleClass('overlay');
    });
});
```

```css
.overlay-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
}
.tparrows{
background :red;
cursor:pointer;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: red;   
     -webkit-animation-name: bg-color-anim; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: bg-color-anim;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes bg-color-anim {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes bg-color-anim {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tparrows">
<ul >
        <li data-transition="fade"><div class="overlay-wrapper"></div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/250/sports/1/Lorem%20Pixel/" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"/>
          <h1 class="tp-caption large sfr" data-x="30" data-y="213" data-speed="600" data-start="800" data-easing="Sine.easeOut"><span>Some Text</span></h1>
          <h2 class="tp-caption medium sfr" data-x="30" data-y="310" data-speed="800" data-start="900" data-easing="Sine.easeOut"><span>Some Text</span></h2>
          <h3 class="tp-caption small sfr" data-x="30" data-y="450" data-speed="900" data-start="1000" data-easing="Sine.easeOut"><span><span class="budicon-plus"></span>Some Text</span></h3>

        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</html>
```

OR

Other way remove overlay class from the element and add it again on that elemetn see below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tparrows").on('click', function () {  
       $(".overlay-wrapper").removeClass('overlay');
       $(".overlay-wrapper").addClass('overlay');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh,I tried both versions. There isn't any change when I add the removeClass function. After the first click the background is added without animation. With the toggleClass function every second slider is being overlayed.

Comment: @pierre : I updated above answer, have a look. But when an animation is finished, it changes back to its original style. In above example, click on red part and animation will start.